# Why is static casting of braced list to an array disallowed?

Tags: c++, arrays, casting

If this is allowed:

```
(int[]){ 1, 2, 3 };
```

Then why is this not allowed too?

```
static_cast<int[]>({ 1, 2, 3 });
```

Is it because a braced list doesn't represent anything in this context? Then why can I cast it to an array using an explicit cast? I can also iterate over such a list:

```
for (const auto& i : { 1, 2, 3 })
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

Edit: If the first line represents a compound literal, what is the type of `{ 1, 2, 3 }` in the last line?

Comment: are you sure that "this" is allowed and that it does what you think it does?

Comment: It compiles and seems to do what it seems that it does, that's all I know.

Comment: `(int[]){ 1, 2, 3 };` is not a cast; it's called compound literal (C99) and is *not* allowed in C++ (it's probably supported as an extension by your compiler - gcc & clang do). So it's not equivalent/comparable to `static_cast`.

Comment: That line does nothing, so how do you know that it does anything? Anyhow, your logic is a tiny bit flawed. C++ casts are in general much more restrictive than the c-style cast. From the top of my head I cannot tell you an example of a c-style cast that fails to compile

Comment: Okay, is casting to arrays *always* forbidden?

Comment: Note that it *is* allowed if you use a type alias: `using T = int[]; T{1, 2, 3}` works fine. The only issue is that the name of the type is not a "single word" in your original example. [cppreference's page on casts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) lists my syntax as syntax 5 and even notes that it's capable of creating arrays.

Comment: @idclev463035818 What  I meant to say is that this results in an object that essentially behaves like an array. E.g. `for (const auto& i : (int[]){ 1, 2, 3 }) // do something`.

Comment: @NikolaPantelic `for (const auto& i : { 1, 2, 3 })` - here what we have is a *braced initializer list* which is allowed in the *range based for loop* (C++11). Although, it *looks* like an array, it's not.

Comment: @P.P Is the resulting object of type `std::initializer_list<int>`?

Comment: @NikolaPantelic Yes, that's the resulting type here. See [initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list): "a braced-init-list is bound to auto, including in a ranged for loop".